# Wordpress custom template not showing in custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I'm trying to use a custom page template within a custom post type. However the templates option will not display within the post type, when trying to add a new page. Please see the code below:

functions.php for the custom post type:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_product' );

function register_cpt_product() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Products', 'product' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Product', 'product' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'product' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Product', 'product' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Product', 'product' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New Product', 'product' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View Product', 'product' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Products', 'product' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No products found', 'product' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No products found in Trash', 'product' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Product:', 'product' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Products', 'product' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => 'Product pages',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,

        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page'
    );

    register_post_type( 'product', $args );
}
```

page template (except of template tag)

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Product
*/
?>
```

Comment: What you trying to achieve? What is the filename of your Template?

Comment: template is single-product.php. I'm simply trying to use this template with the custom page type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have page templates of any Wordpress template files:

Like:

```
archive-*.php
category-*.php
single-*.php // in your case
```

or any other.

But you can have page templates for `page-*.php` or your custom `filename.php`:

```
any-file-name.php
page-*.php
```

Rename your `single-product.php` file to something else or just remove `single` and rename it something else

Like:

```
my-single-product.php // this should work
```

Remember `single-product.php` will be used to render your custom post types (product) single post content.

**Edited:**

Page templates are only for Wordpress builtin pages. A custom post type is supposed to just have one template. If you have a need to change it then you will most likely want to create another post type or just use pages or the regular posts.

Sources: [Page Attributes options for custom post types](http://mysitemyway.com/support/topic/page-attributes-options-for-custom-post-types)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I've renamed the file and am still having the same issue. Previously the template worked with the standard pages (and showed up on pages) however it has neither shown up on my custom post type (now or before). Therefore I think it's more of an issue with defining the post type? Cheers

Comment: E.g. the templates aren't selectable from the post attributes options.

Comment: @PhilHudson to display single post content yes it should be `single-product.php` if to display post type product use `archive-product.php`